# Question about Pop-up message design

Tags: mobile-application, popup, multiple-products

I am a UX Rookie & just joined this forum.

I & my team, which are Seniors, are working on a particular screen that contains the following details:

1. User selects a product
2. User than selects some option
3. User can add additional item (max:4)
4. Lastly, user taps the next button

There is a scenario that if the user adds a new item (eg. add a 3rd item
after adding 2 items) but decides to tap next, than a pop up message appears which states that the product selection is incomplete.

Ususally in alot programs (e.g. Word, Paint, etc.), the dialog message displays "Yes" to exit & "No" to stay. We are quite naturally used to this flow.

However, my team is doing the opposite; "Yes" to stay & "No" to exit.

We naturally are used to clicking "Yes" in those situations. Sometimes, we click "Yes" without reading the prompt message. And, haven't seen any programs where we click "No" to exit.

Since we didn't perform any user testing, I cannot deduce that the users will be confused with my team design logic. We all behave differently when interacting with a product.

I stated to my team that their logic may create confusion initially. They stated that their thought process is better.

1. Are there any programs or some apps that direct the users to exit the program with unsaved work when clicking/tapping "No" instead of "Yes" from the pop up?
2. My team stated that their thought process was better. Your thought on this?

Note that this concept isn't final & we are exploring other ideas to create better experience.

Like said earlier, I am a UX Rookie & looking forward to hear your feedback.

Comment: What is the actual message in the dialog?

Comment: "Product selection is incomplete. Do you wish to add another product?". If "Yes", than stay at the page. Otherwise, they get directed to the next screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects to your question. One of them is this:

> User can add additional item (max:4).

but you say that if he adds 2 ( hence, *less than 4*), the system considers this incomplete and displays a dialog. I'm not sure if this was an error in your description or if this is actually happening. If so, the dialog could be solved by reducing the ambiguity: either it's `max: 4` (in which case nothing should be displayed if `> 4` options are selected), or it's `exactly 4` (in which case you could just disable the "Next" button), or it's `AT LEAST 4` (in which case you could disable the button and perhaps display a note about this requirement).

Apart from that, the answer **"yes"** or **"no"** is very bad UX, because it's ambiguous as hell (you asking this question are the proof).

I suggest that instead you label buttons with the expected behavior, such as **"I want to add more**" and **"Continue"** (or whatever option you need). This way, you tell the user EXACTLY what to expect from interacting with these elements.

## Additional Reading:

[**5 Rules for choosing the right words on button labels**](https://uxmovement.com/buttons/5-rules-for-choosing-the-right-words-on-button-labels/)

Comment: For your first response, I made a typo in my question. What I wanted was when a user adds a new item but decides to click Next, Yes/No pop up appears.
Example: If I add a 3rd item but decided to click Next, the pop up message displays. So its not limited to second item only. I will edit my question. Thanks for pointing it out.
For your second response, the link shared was very helpful.
Is it possible that Yes/No would work for questions proceeding them like "do you have social security number?" There can be different sets of questions depending on user response.